# Unable to customize bootstrap file-input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-file-upload

I am trying to implement bootstrap file input form [GitHub](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput) in asp.net.

Below is my .aspc file code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

        <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-fileinput/js/fileinput.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
     <script>
         $("#input-id").fileinput({
             'showUpload': false,
             'maxFileCount': 5,
             'showPreview': false,
             'mainClass': "input-group-lg"
         });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="input-id" type="file" class="file-loading" multiple>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It works. But I need to customize it.

1. I do not want preview of files ('showPreview': false)
2. I do not want to show Upload button ('showUpload': false)
3. I want to limit number of files ('maxFileCount': 5)

I have used required plugins for customization.

But Still I get default preview/output.

Can someone help with this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has minor errors. You need to add "multiple" directive to your input tag and change class to: "file-loading".

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <input id="input-id" type="file" class="file-loading" multiple>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here is a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/16jut54d/

Comment: and what external css and js files are you including?

Comment: I have updated my code as you said. Now all I am getting is a gif loading image on output :(

Comment: And with same input it gives correct ouput on jsfiddle.net. How is this possible!

Comment: If you click on external resources in jsfiddle you will see all of them. Basically, bootstrap js and css as well as fileinput js and css. Also, maybe create your own jsfiddle for use to see how it is implemented.